# Running background http server in Android

Tags: android, rest, service, embeddedwebserver

I am developing a suit of games o custom tablets with NO internet connection neither wifi, to ease the process i'm using HTML5, but since PhoneGap uses a standard WebView i moved to CocoonJS to achieve better performance.

The problem is that CocoonJS only provides hardware acceleration and a couple of useless(in my case) native APIs.

Is there a way to develop a Native Application that runs a background service exposing a sort of lightweight webserver where i can develop a REST interface for setting common options?

This would solve all my problems enabling me to save my progress and other stuf making AJAX calls from Javascript to something like "GET localhost:9000/score/"

Comment: do you want to create a webserver in which you can do get requests

Comment: exactely, in the end i reached my goal by using an open source server and modifying a bit

still not being able to do it on my own into my app